# Automatic Calculator

Tags: javascript, jquery, calculator

i am pretty new in JS (just very small knowladge) but i want to learn. I Want to do automatic calculator for my self but im stucked. https://jsfiddle.net/oj5s97ua/1/ I want to do this:

```js
$('input').keyup(function() {
  var firstValue = Number($('#first').val());
  var secondValue = Number($('#second').val());
  var thirdValue = Number($('#third').val());
  var fourthValue = Number($('#total_expenses1').val());
  var fifthValue = Number($('#total_expenses2').val());

  $('#total_expenses1').html(secondValue / firstValue);
  $('#total_expenses2').html(thirdValue - firstValue);
  $('#total_expenses3').html(fourthValue * fifthValue);
});

/*
$('input').keyup(function(){ 
  var firstValue = parseFloat($('#first').val()); 
  var secondValue = parseFloat($('#second').val()); 
  var thirdValue = parseFloat($('#third').val());
  var fourthValue = parseFloat($('#total_expenses1').val());
  var fifthValue = parseFloat($('#total_expenses2').val());
  document.getElementById('#total_expenses1').value(secondValue / firstValue);
  document.getElementById('#total_expenses2').value(thirdValue - firstValue);
  document.getElementById('#total_expenses3').value(fourthValue * fifthValue);
});*/
```

Many thanks for any answer! :)

Comment: You've got the wrong tag for the questions.  Change it to javascript.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do?

Comment: If you edit your question to include what kind of output you're expecting to see as the user, that will help us help you get where you need to go.